# cucumber syntax error with "umlaut"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, syntax, cucumber, debian

I have some interesting issue with cucumber on rails. A colleague of mine can use Umlaute, such as ä ö ü from the german language. I can not. I just get

`syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end`
pointing at "Gültig bis".

We both use the same setup: rails 3.0.4, cucumber (0.10.3), cucumber-rails (0.5.1) and their common dependencies.

Is it possible, because I am running cucumber tests on a VM (project included as shared folder, gems bundled inside. Confusing for me but working) with Debian 5 and he uses his local machine with mac OS 10.6??

Anybody heard of something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that working for to long on a problem shows the wrong answers on google.

Was a misspelling of headline:
`#encoding: UTF-8` needs to be the first line in your own defined steps-file.